# How to make a count down timer in Notification's view?

Tags: android, android-notifications, countdowntimer

I figured out how to make custom views using [`RemoteViews`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html) class. I also know how to use [`Chronometer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html) and [`ProgressBar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) inside of [`RemoteViews`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html).

But how to make a count down [`View`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html), almost exactly the same as [`Chronometer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html) but with the difference that it will be counting down instead of up?

I tried to copy the source of [`Chronometer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html) class and modify it so it will fit my needs, but there are annotations like `@android.view.RemotableViewMethod`, which i can not import to my project. Unfortunately, without annotations it is not working, because [`RemoteViews`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html) is using them to pass values.

My second idea was to extend the [`Chronometer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html) class and override proper methods, but they are `private`.

Any ideas, is it possible? (And extra question, because I'm not sure: If the method is annotated and I override this method, is the annotation inherited?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe you're going to be able to use a custom class directly with `RemoteViews` even if it's derived from one of the supported classes (annotations are *not* inherited). You could try using a `TextView`, counting down in a `Service` with a reference to the `RemoteViews` object and updating from there.

Comment: Wouldn't it be resource consuming? Anyway, how to tell if the View is currently viewed or not?

Comment: It's certainly not cheap, I just can't think of another way to handle this really. If this is going to be more than just a test app and you try this approach, you'll definitely want to look at trying to find situations where you can pause this work (e.g. when the screen is off). I don't believe there's a good way to see if that view in the notification tray is visible either.

Comment: Yepp, there is no way doing it in elegant and effective way. I gave up this feature. Let this question be a time-saver for the others who want to do the same. Beware!