# countdown in the time field of a notification

Tags: android, notifications, overriding, countdown

I'm working with [Notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) and I would like to use a function such as [setUsesChronometer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setUsesChronometer%28boolean%29), it displays a chronometer in the top right corner of the notification.

The thing is I would like to use a count-down instead of a count-up.
How can I do that ?

Thank you.

Comment: Looking for something like that too

Comment: This is duplicate question, please search before.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403662/how-to-make-a-count-down-timer-in-notifications-view
Good Luck.